# integrating exponential

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How can you integrate $\frac{e^{x-3}}{x^4} dx$.

I tried integration by parts but it's not possible.

Is some substitution possible ?

I started off solving the diff eqn $(xy^2 + 3e^{x-3})dx - x^2ydy = 0$
It's a non-exact first order equation whose integrating factor is $1/x^4$.

Finally I got to the equation where I needed to integrate $\frac{e^{x-3}}{x^4} dx.$
But I can't seem to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried integration by parts but it's not possible.

Actually it is, you just have to do it repeatedly, $\big($three or four times$\big)$, with regards to $\dfrac1{x^n}$, and then lastly employ the [exponential integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). You should finally be able to arrive at $\dfrac1{6~e^3}\bigg[\text{Ei}(x)-e^x\cdot$ $\cdot\dfrac{x^2+x+2}{x^3}\bigg]$

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that the integral of that doesn't have a closed form as your expression there seems very related to the Gamma function and the exponential integral.

Comment: Gamma function is e^(-x) * x^(n-1).

Comment: Yes, hence why I said related (to $e^{3}\Gamma(-5)$, except that doesn't converge) and not equal to.

Comment: -5 is negative , n >0 in gamma function

Comment: It's really not, it's called analytic continuation. It's infinite for negative integers but you're looking at an indefinite integral and not an infinite integral. Trust me, there's no closed form.